# com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: android, annotations

when i using android Annotation,found this question,who could help me?
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'. > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'

def AAVersion = '4.1.0'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.administrator.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
    apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
    compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"
}

apt {
    arguments {
        androidManifestFile variant.outputs[0]?.processResources?.manifestFile
        resourcePackageName 'com.example.administrator.myapplication'
    }

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: add `multiDexEnabled true` in your `build.gradle`

Answer (score 0):

Set multiDexEnabled true in your gradle file

```
 defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.administrator.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```